# Handling four Uiviewcontrollers in One Scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have One scrollview and four UIViewcontrollers now i want to add that four viewcontrollers into one scrollview and also handle scroll option for that 4 viewcontrollers

any one know plz answer this.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer UIPageControl  ... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html

Tutorial:
http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/